# What decomposes the decomposers?

Tags: decomposition

Decomposers feed on dead organisms. What feeds on them? In particular:

1. What decomposes mold?
2. If fly larvae feed on animal dung, what eats their dung?
3. Are all fungi eaten by animals? If not, what decomposes them?

Comment: Just think of it like scavengers but at the microscopic level. Microorganisms can scavenge each other just like larger animals can.

Comment: Maybe your thinking on a "food chain" paradigm. So, who eat the specie that are at the end of the chain?. In a "food web" paradigm there is not such a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably (1) "fungi and other decomposers", (2) "fungi and other decomposers", (3) "fungi and other decomposers".

If you're interested in *precise* answers ("exactly *which* taxa are responsible for the decomposition of *some particular type* of dead tissue?") you probably won't get an answer. In general the answer is "detritivores chew on it, break it down, extract some of the useful material, poop it out; then a broad spectrum of other decomposers (fungi, bacteria, protozoans) do the rest of the job".